# Which Python Magic Method is Pandas Using?

Tags: python, pandas, getter-setter

I have a class that contains a pandas DataFrame (self.my_df), and updating self.my_df does not work how I expect it to. Here's a simplified version of the code that illustrates my problem:

```
class my_obj(object):
    @property
    def my_df(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_my_df"):
            self._my_df = pandas.DataFrame({ "A" : [1,2,3,],
                                             "B" : [4,5,6]}).fillna("")
        print("Retrieving!")
        return self._my_df

    @my_df.setter
    def my_df(self, my_new_df):
        print("Setting!")
        self._my_df = my_new_df.copy()
```

Here's what happens when I (try to) call these methods (from inside a separate instance method that I don't think matters here):

```
ipdb> self.my_df
Retrieving!
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
ipdb> self.my_df.loc[2, "B"] = "x"
Retrieving!
ipdb> self.my_df
Retrieving!
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  x
ipdb> self._my_df
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  x
```

I would expect `self.my_df.loc[2, "B"] = "x"` to call the setter, which it doesn't, or——if it *doesn't*——then I would expect self._my_df **not to be set**, which it is.

What's happening here? My real situation is much more complex, but I believe this is the root confusion for me.

Thanks for helping me clear this up.

Comment: The setter would be used with `self.my_df = ...`,  There is no pandas magic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to see what's happening if you break down the steps. Instead of

```
self.my_df.loc[2, "B"] = "x"
```

consider

```
temp = self.my_df         # Clearly this should call the get method
temp.loc[2, "B"] = "x"    # Changes the pandas object
```

These two snippets achieve the same result. The setter will not be called, since you are not assigning to the `my_df` property of the `my_obj` object. You are retrieving the contents of `self.my_df` (which is a dataframe), and then manipulating it.

A `my_obj` object only holds a reference to a `DataFrame`, so unless you point `my_df` to a different object, the setter will not be called. With your code, the `my_obj` object still points to the same dataframe, but you have manipulated the dataframe's contents.

Comment: Thanks; so in your example, `temp = self.my_df` copies a pointer, not the actual pandas object?

Comment: Yes (as does your code). This is a feature of python, not pandas. Everything is a reference and the contents of an object (its data) are not copied by assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The setter will be called if/when you ***set*** `self.my_df`.

I.e. if you did `self.my_df = 2` that's when the setter would get called.

What you're doing is modifying the object that is associated with `self.my_df`. So the your code is ***getting*** the dataframe, and then modifying it.